# CSS MAC OS renders font and style different

Tags: css, fonts, cross-browser

Hi i do have 2 problems with MAC Browsers.

First: I'm using Chrome and FF on MAC. But the font looks more blurred and Bold.
It looks right on Windows 7, i'm using the same browsers

Second: My padding and margins doesn't work on MAC OS too. Same browsers, CHROME, FF and SAFARI.

```
.mynav li {
  padding: 10px 0;
}
```

Again when i checked it on a Windows OS. Same Browsers, the padding is there.

Comment: Could you add your font declarations, along with a link to whatever page you're working on?

Comment: How the fonts look depends on the system settings. But the padding should be the same. So yes, we need an example page. By the way, Safari on Windows no longer updates - the latest version is over a year old; so it probably differs between Windows and your Mac.